# Python list cumulative sum greater than rest of elements in list

Tags: python, algorithm, list

I want to write an function which will return least number for which cumsum is greater than rest of list. List will have values -1 and 1 only. list may have million of elements.
e.g.

> v = [1 1 -1 1 -1 1 -1 1]

here answer should be 2, because

```
1) 1 > 1 is False 
2) (1 + 1) 2 > 0 (-1 + 1 -1 +1 -1 +1)
```

one more example

> v = [-1 -1 1 1]

answer 4

code I tried already:

```
def cumsum_grt(v):
    for i in range(1, len(v)):
        k = i
        if sum(v[:k]) > sum(v[k:]):
            break
    return k
```

This function works fine, but is there any way to improve performance? It is failing due to not able to calculate result in few seconds for large list.

Comment: you should probably calculate the cumulative sum in a, well, *cumulative* way.

Comment: Not answering the question, but `k` is not needed. In `python` the value of `i` continue to exist after the loop ended, so you can use the `i` anywhere you used `k`.

Comment: why my question is flagged as negative?

Comment: @BhaveshGhodasara What is the expected result for `[-1, -1, -1, -1]`? I wrote code that would return `1` as `0` is greater than `-4`.

Comment: @BhaveshGhodasara, do you realize that `sum(lst[:0]) > sum(lst[0:])` will give `True` for `lst = [-1, -1, -1,-1] ` ?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest appologies, I missed that..yes answer should be 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is linear, O(N), while your version is something like O(N*N):

```
def cumsum_grt(v):
    so_far = 0
    the_rest = sum(v)
    for i in range(len(v)):
        if so_far > the_rest :
            return i
        so_far += v[i]
        the_rest -= v[i]
    return len(v)
```

Comment: I am testing timing of this solution. I will accept it answer after testing all solutions given here.

Comment: shouldn't this function return `1` for the input `[-1,-1,-1,-1]` as "least number for which cumsum is greater than rest of list." ? the 1st number `-1` is greater than remaining `-3`. But It returns `0`

Comment: @lenik : thank you so much . I will try to understand logic now :)

Comment: @BhaveshGhodasara the logic is really simple, there are two parts of the list, the beginning and the rest of the list. It's pretty much the same as you did, except, I don't calculate the sum of these parts every time, I just add/subtract the current element to keep them updated, this makes things much faster.

Comment: @lenik yes I got it.My question sounds so stupid now :).

Answer (score 2):

```
def cumsum_grt(v):
    total_sum = sum(v)
    curr_sum = v[0]
    for i in range(1, len(v)):
        if curr_sum > (total_sum - abs(curr_sum)):
            break
        curr_sum += v[i]
    return i
```

Tests:

```
lst = [1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1]
lst2 = [1, 1, -1, 20, -1, 15, -1, 1]
lst3 = [-2, -1, 4, -1]
lst4 = [-1,-1,-1,-1]

print(cumsum_grt(lst))   # 2
print(cumsum_grt(lst2))  # 4
print(cumsum_grt(lst3))  # 3
print(cumsum_grt(lst4))  # 1
```

---

Time performance measurements:

```
In [101]: lst = [1, 1, -1, 20, -1, 15, -1, 5, -1, -2, 40]                                                                    

In [102]: %timeit cumsum_grt(lst)                                                                                            
70.3 µs ± 175 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

In [103]: %timeit cumsum_grt_lenik(lst)                                                                                      
8.23 µs ± 27.9 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

In [104]: %timeit cumsum_grt_roman(lst)                                                                                      
8.22 µs ± 30.4 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Comment: don't you need to subtract something from the `total_sum` ?

Comment: v = list(np.random.choice([-1,1], size=30000)) I tested with this list. tested your function with lenik's function. Lenik's function took 2.99ms, your's took around 5.98ms while mine took 10.6 second

Comment: @BhaveshGhodasara, I don't agree with your timings, see my update with timings from interactive session

Comment: my approach is not 2 times slower than @lenik's approach. They are close in timings, his approach may be slightly faster

Comment: @RomanPerekhresttotally agree. I never meant your solution is twice slower than Lenik.

Comment: I tested both function with following code in my jupyter notebook : %time cumsum_grt(v) ...I completed multiple iteration and found Lenik's is slightly faster than your's so I upvoted your answer as well. Thanks.

Comment: @BhaveshGhodasara, welcome, that's ok (+1 to question)

Comment: плюс один за настойчивость и старания =)

Comment: @lenik, Благодарю )

Answer (score 1):

You could use `next` with `itertools.accumulate`, comparing the current accumulated sum to the total sum minus the accumulated sum, then use `enumerate` to get the index of that position. `chain` with `[0]` for the position before the first element of the list.

```
>>> from itertools import accumulate, chain
>>> v = [1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1]
>>> s = sum(v)
>>> next((i for i, a in enumerate(chain([0], accumulate(v))) if a > s - a), len(v))
2
```

Beware: Do not calculate `sum(v)` within the `if` condition, else it will be O(n²). The `len(v)` at the end is the default value in case the accumulated sum is not enough for any element.

Comment: OP says the answer should be `2` ??

Comment: I am testing timing of this solution. I will accept it answer after testing all solutions given here.